# How to represent a set containing sets following a certain pattern in mathematical notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set that contains the following sets:

$$\{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, ... \{1, 2, 3, ... , n\}\}$$

Is there an elegant way to represent the above using mathematical notation? I'm looking for something like

$$1 + 2 + 3 + ~~...~~ + n = \sum_{k=1}^n k$$

Comment: $\{\{1,\dots,k\} : k=1,\dots,n\}$, where $\{1,\dots,k\}$ denotes the set $\{j \in \mathbb Z : 1 \leq j \leq k\}$.

Comment: @azif00 could you post as an answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard notation in combinatorics is to write $[n]$ for the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. With this notation, you could write your set as
$\bigl\{\ [k] \mid 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n \bigr\}$.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I use the notation $$\mathbb{N}_n=\{k\in\mathbb{N}: 1\leq k\leq n\}$$ The set you have in your post would be $$\{\mathbb{N}_m: m\in \mathbb{N}_n\}$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.